# Are there any file-based static cache options for Craft CMS?

Tags: cache

Is there an option for storing the pages generated by Craft CMS as flat, static HTML files?

The model used by static driver from ExpressionEngine's CE Cache add-on works pretty well:

Each page request hits a mod_rewrite rule, which checks to see if an HTML file for that page exists in the static cache directory.

If said file exists, it gets served to the browser.

If the file doesn't exist, the CMS generates the output, which is then saved as a cache file for the next user who hits that URL.

It only works in cases where the entire page can be saved, but, it's insanely fast and pretty easy to implement compared to other caching solutions.

... is there anything like that available for Craft CMS?

Comment: FYI: I've been working on a flat, static HTML Cache for Craft. It busts the cache after an hour or when an entry has been updated. It is currently in beta, could use feedback :) https://github.com/craftapi/htmlcache

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone has recently developed a standalone static HTML caching plugin for Craft CMS which does similar to what you're after:

[HTML Cache plugin for Craft CMS](https://github.com/craftapi/htmlcache)

This Craft plugin will generate static HTML files for your website. No need for Reddis/Varnish setups anymore!

- Improves the speed drastically: 300-1500MS to 2-50MS (depending on
  server setup) if ubercache is enabled from the settings page
- Busts the cache automatically when an entry has been updated
- Cache duration time can be set; defaults to 3600 seconds (1 hour)
- Active development and support through Craft's Slack

NOTE: This plugin is still in beta, so please test if this plugin works as expected on a development environment before pushing to a production site.

Comment: Just note that it appears to bust the entire cache when updating an entry. If you have hundreds or thousands of pages on your site, this might be a significant downside.

Answer (score 3):

You can also implement FastCGI Cache for static page caching pretty easily; check out:

[Static Page Caching with Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/static-caching-with-craft-cms)

Comment: +1 more people need to know about nginx's ``fastcgi_cache``, a great gem IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing that I'm aware of and a scan through Straight Up Craft's [plugin directory](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins) isn't revealing anything, either.

There are, however, some that integrate with [Fastly](https://github.com/onedesign/craft-fastly) and [Varnish](http://plugins.supercooldesign.co.uk/plugin/cache-monster), where you could do all sorts of static caching strategies.